# Regex for Function Block Parsing

Tags: python, regex, parsing, expression

I need some regex help.

What im trying to make is a function block parsing pattern.

the functions look like this:

```
fn name() {
    contents
}

fn name2() {
    contents2
}
```

I use this pattern to parse it: `(fn \w+\s*\(.*\)\s*{.+(?<=}))`

It works as expected, but instead of matching only to the first }, which should be the end of the "name" function, it keeps going until the last } find in the whole document basically. Can someone help me fix it?

Much appreciated.

Comment: If `contents` can contain `n` sets of paired braces for any `n > 0`, then you cannot properly parse this with regular expressions as it is not a regular language.

Comment: Got a solution for that, the problem was only the block parsing. Thanks!

Comment: For me this looks like a problem where a lexical analysis pattern would be a better solution over regular expressions.

Comment: yup. Its a small transpiler to practice regex, i chose this method because im not familiar with lexical analysis stuff.

Answer (score 3):

With .* and .+ you are matching any character greedily, that's why you consume everything up to the last } character. Change .* to .*? and .+ to .+?

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/pC0hF0/1

While this fixes your temporary problem, also note the comment by @CollinD about nested braces.

Comment: Thanks. Been messing with it for a while.